# How to change the prototype.js URL to a Google hosted version?

Tags: magento

I notice Magento uses prototype.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript\" src="http://www.example.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
```

My question is how I can change the URL to a Google hosted version of prototype.js which is minified.

I tried to change the URL in page.xml but it doesn’t work as the URL always starts with http://www.example.com

Any idea how to specify an absolute URL for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addJs`, `addCSS`, etc. action methods are specifically designed for local files.  You can't use them to add files at external URLs to the page.  Instead, you'll need to add the URLs directly to Magento's head template.

You can do this by copying the **base** head template at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

To your theme's template folder

app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/page/html/head.phtml

If you look at that template, you'll see the HTML and PHP template code used to render the head element of all Magento HTML pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

You can simply add HTML tags to this file to add any additional script tags you need.  Don't forget to use the `removeItem` method to ensure the local prototype.js is NOT rendered.

If you wanted to get really fancy, rather than edit the template you could use Layout XML to add new scripts with something like this

```
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text" name="cdn_prototype">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script>]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

(advice here is 1.6.1 specific, but should apply to most, if not all, versions of Magento)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find an extension for this purpose at the ever-helpful Inchoo blog ([link](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/)).

If you read through the post, it will help understand some of the Block and layout architecture that Magento uses too.

Answer (score 0):

[This Magento extension](https://github.com/vsushkov/Oggetto-Page) allows to include external JS and CSS files via layout XML files.
After installing the extension, put the following line in `page.xml`:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>absolute_js</type><name>http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js</name>
```

Don't forget to use the `removeItem` method to ensure the local prototype.js is NOT rendered.

Answer (score -6):

Link to the source directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script>
```

Or via Google API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("prototype", "1.6.0.2");</script>
```

Read the [manual](http://prototypejs.org/2008/5/27/prototype-hosted-on-google-s-servers), Search online before asking

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think you know how Magento layout files work.

Comment: Just replacing the example.com link with the URL above. Can't?